# CSS Make text beneath overlay bg opaque/visible

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[My Result](http://imgur.com/6ylQj8D)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap916.jpg)

I have an overlay color with 0.6 opacity over my huge background picture; but this overlay darkens the text (h1 and h2 from the middle)

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 57.5%;
  background: url("../img/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.bg-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 57.5%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #424252;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main-header">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          <!-- This whole DIV I want to be visible -->
          <h2>AN EASY WAY TO BUILD A WEBSITE</h2>
          <hr/>
          <h1>WITH MINT</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- end content-->
      </div>
      <!-- end container-->
    </div>
    <!-- end jumbotron-->
    <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
    <!-- This is the overlay -->
  </div>
  <!-- end main-header-->
</header>
```

Giving the navbar-brand and anchor elements opacity worked, but I can't manange to do it for the content

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've provided is `opacity` set to `0.6`. Could you please clarify which element you're referring to?

Comment: You may benefit from reading this SO help article: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: bg-overlay is the element, I edited now ^

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the `z index` to -1 and then put a div in for the text alone and then work with the opacity. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v1wk08w/1/)

```css
.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-default {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
  color: #eaecf1;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 57.5%;
  background: url("../img/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  background: red;
  background-size: contain;
}
.jumbotron h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.text {
  opacity: .6
}
.bg-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 57.5%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #424252;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="index.html" class="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <!-- here is the navbar code -->
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end row -->
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text" <h2>AN EASY WAY TO BUILD A WEBSITE</h2>
            <hr/>
            <h1>WITH MINT</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end content-->
      </div>
      <!-- end container-->
    </div>
    <!-- end jumbotron-->
    <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
    <!-- This is the overlay -->
  </div>
  <!-- end main-header-->
```

Comment: or you could just adjust the z index for the text div http://jsfiddle.net/8v1wk08w/2/

Comment: Chaning the z index to -1 makes the overlay dissapear

And using the z index 50 in text div isn't working

P.S.: I've edited the post for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Put the overlay in an ::after selector. 
Opacity will coutn for the whole div and won't be resolved with z-index.
Instead you can use the ::after selecter to stack the opacity layer on top of the backgorund image.

This link might help you out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/